# How to retrieve the value of $(Config) using ToolsAPI?

Tags: delphi, toolsapi

When writing the Delphi expert using ToolsAPI, we may use GetEnvironmentVariable to retrieve the environment variables available to the current Delphi IDE process.  However, this only works if the variables are define in your current user account setting or in Delphi's environment variables setting under

```
Tools | Options | Environment Options | Environment Variables.
```

Some variables like $(Config) in Delphi 2010 / XE are available for used but it doesn't appear as environment variables.  We may get a list of variables by turn on "Diagnostic" in Verbosity setting.  The $(Config) variable appears in Diagnostic output when compiling a project in Delphi IDE.

Is there a way to retrieve the value of $(Config) in ToolsAPI?

Answer (score 4):

The project's `ProjectOptions` property can be cast to `IOTAProjectOptionsConfigurations`.

```
var
  Project: IOTAProject;
begin
  // ... obtain reference to the project
  ShowMessage((Project.ProjectOptions as IOTAProjectOptionsConfigurations).ActiveConfigurationName);
end;
```

Comment: What if I need to retrieve other variable's value that not define in environment variables?  The reason I ask this is I try to do a workaround solution to fix an IDE bug: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=92507

Comment: That probably depends on what the "other variables" are.

Comment: If we have more than one build configurations, e.g.: "debug" and "release", we may perform "release" build in IDE while "debug" is the active configuration.  In the answer you given, I never have chance to get the value of $(Config) as "release", it always return "debug" in this case.

Comment: `ActiveConfiguration` returns the active configuration. To enumerate all defined configurations use the `ConfigurationCount` and `Configurations` properties of the `IOTAProjectOptionsConfigurations` interface.

Comment: I am aware of the ConfigurationCount and Configurations properties.  I wish to retrieve the actual configuration when build a project in my Toolsapi expert.  If I can retrieve the value of $(Config) during runtime, then my problem is solved.  The ActiveConfiguration is not always the build configuration for current compilation task.

Comment: The actual configuration? Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that. Or "the value of $(Config) during runtime". It's actually runtime of the IDE, or runtime of the compiled project? It would help if you could ask more clearly. Perhaps you need to write and register a compile notifier by implementing `IOTAProjectCompileNotifier`? I have no idea from what you wrote.

Comment: Let me rephrase.  I have 2 build configurations: "debug" and "release".  "debug" is the active configuration.  ActiveConfiguration will always return "debug" if I invoke the function in IDE toolsapi runtime.  If I right click on "release" build (not the active configuration) and select build, how may I get the configuration of "release"?  I have tried IOTAProjectCompileNotifier and it almost work.  If I invoke AddCompileNotifier and RemoveCompileNotifier for few times, the IDE  prompt Access violation in module 'delphicoreide150.bpl'.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to use the notifier - there you have a chance to determine which configuration is currently being used for the build process. The access violation probably means you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I have try to figured out what's wrong for day but can't find what's wrong.  Can I send you the code to review and hopefully you may point me the mistake I made?  Thank you.

Comment: Post your code here as a question; then you have a better chance to get a good reply.

Comment: Thanks.  I have post a new question in topic [How to implement IOTAProjectCompileNotifier of Delphi's ToolsAPI ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439666/how-to-implement-iotaprojectcompilenotifier-of-delphis-toolsapi)