# Can I revert the changes of a Delphi XE project by Toolsapi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, toolsapi

I am writing Delphi XE expert.  The expert switch the build configuration from "debug" to "release", perform build and switch back to "release" back to "debug".

While switch the build configuration, only the .dproj file has modified.  The project state become modified.

Is that possible to revert back the project file state with ToolsAPI?

Comment: You don't want to change anything in the project, just to change the "project has been modified" state. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, did you sort out the AV in your previous question? If so could you please add an answer to the question explaining what the solution was.

Comment: Once the build configuration changed, the project state change to modified.  I just want to revert the project state to "clean" or "unmodified" as I didn't change anything in the project files.

Comment: The .dproj file is modified by a change to the active build configuration.

Comment: I don't have solution for the previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439666/how-to-implement-iotaprojectcompilenotifier-of-delphis-toolsapi).  I still encounter AV no matter how I use the RemoveCompileIdentifier.  I feel this is Delphi IDE bug.

Comment: @Chau It won't be a bug. It's a brand new feature in XE. They won't have added it without making sure it runs.

Comment: @David: Have you tested? Or if you don't have the environment to test, I can let you access my desktop via remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the project's modified state easily using the IOTAProjectOptions40 interface from ToolsAPI. It contains a property "ModifiedState", simply assign this to False to specify the project as "unmodified".

Enjoy :)